# ViewModel receives null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi am working on a simple form submit in asp.net core 3.1 version. I need to use view model to get data from form. The problem is when I try to submit it, the tax model receives null on controller. Everything seems to be correct but still it receives null.

My viewmodel

[image]

My model

[image]

My form

[image]

My controller

[image]

Comment: What exactly is NULL: the entire TaxViewModel? The TaxModel? The TaxName? And which .NET version are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could you please add your code snippet instead of screenshots. Additionally, all `TaxViewModel` are null or `TaxModel` is null? `HeadingModel` and `List<TaxModel>` should be null because you are not sending any value for that.

Comment: Why are you sending `TaxViewModel` to you `Controller`? According to you design, you should send `TaxModel` and then bind what is required on your `Controller`.

Comment: I am using dotnet core 3.1 version. The tax model receives null in controller.  My requirements is to use view model because I need to add one more form in same screen.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net core bind data with name attribute,try to replace:

```
    <input type="text" asp-for="Tax.TaxName" class="form-control" id="TaxName" placeholder="Tax Name" />
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="tax.Tax.TaxName" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax Name" />
```

result:
[image]